# How can I generate a random number within a range in Rust?

Tags: random, rust, rust-obsolete

> Editor's note: This code example is from a version of Rust prior to 1.0 and is not syntactically valid Rust 1.0 code. Updated versions of this code produce different errors, but the answers still contain valuable information.

I came across the following example of how to generate a random number using Rust, but it doesn't appear to work. The example doesn't show which version of Rust it applies to, so perhaps it is out-of-date, or perhaps I got something wrong.

```
// http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/rand/trait.Rng.html

use std::rand;
use std::rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::task_rng();
    let n: uint = rng.gen_range(0u, 10);
    println!("{}", n);
    let m: float = rng.gen_range(-40.0, 1.3e5);
    println!("{}", m);
}
```

When I attempt to compile this, the following error results:

```
test_rand002.rs:6:17: 6:39 error: type `@mut std::rand::IsaacRng` does not
implement any method in scope named `gen_range`
test_rand002.rs:6    let n: uint = rng.gen_range(0u, 10);
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test_rand002.rs:8:18: 8:46 error: type `@mut std::rand::IsaacRng` does not
implement any method in scope named `gen_range`
test_rand002.rs:8    let m: float = rng.gen_range(-40.0, 1.3e5);
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

There is another example (as follows) on the same page (above) that does work. However, it doesn't do exactly what I want, although I could adapt it.

```
use std::rand;
use std::rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::task_rng();
    let x: uint = rng.gen();
    println!("{}", x);
    println!("{:?}", rng.gen::<(f64, bool)>());
}
```

How can I generate a "simple" random number using Rust (e.g.: `i64`) within a given range (e.g.: 0 to n)?

Comment: Links to http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/ mean the version is master.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Editor's note: **This answer is for a version of Rust prior to 1.0 and is not valid in Rust 1.0.** See [Manoel Stilpen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37017052/48136) instead.

This has been changing a lot recently (sorry! it's all been me), and in Rust 0.8 it was called [`gen_integer_range`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.8/std/rand/trait.Rng.html#fn.gen_integer_range) (note the `/0.8/` rather than `/master/` in the URL, if you are using 0.8 you *need* to be reading those docs).

A word of warning: `.gen_integer_range` was entirely incorrect in many ways, the new `.gen_range` doesn't have incorrectness problems.

---

Code for master (where `.gen_range` works fine):

```
use std::rand::{task_rng, Rng};

fn main() {
    // a number from [-40.0, 13000.0)
    let num: f64 = task_rng().gen_range(-40.0, 1.3e4);
    println!("{}", num);
}
```

Comment: I see that for 0.10 and master the documentation says to `use rand::Rng` http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.10/rand/index.html
 so it's a documentation bug probably

Comment: I get `rust.rs:1:17: 1:25 error: unresolved import `std::rand::task_rng`. There is no `task_rng` in `std::rand`
rust.rs:1 use std::rand::{task_rng, Rng};
                          ^~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
` when I try to compile it with `rustc 1.0.0-nightly (b4c965ee8 2015-03-02) (built 2015-03-03)`

Comment: For people who stumble upon this question now: `rand` seems to have become an independent crate on its own, and the answer by Manoel Stilpen below, where you explicitly use that crate, works.

Answer (score 115):

This generates a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 100 (exclusive) using [`Rng::gen_range`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.8.5/rand/trait.Rng.html#method.gen_range):

```
use rand::Rng; // 0.8.5

fn main() {
    // Generate random number in the range [0, 99]
    let num = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..100);
    println!("{}", num);
}
```

Don't forget to add the `rand` dependency to Cargo.toml:

```ini
[dependencies]
rand = "0.8"
```

Comment: this won't even compile there's no method gen_rng rand::prelude::ThreadRng the compiler says

Comment: @nikoss you need to install the rand crate. And as I said add it to cargo.toml

Comment: @nikoss Don't forget to import the trait as well: `use rand::Rng;`

Answer (score 16):

The documentation for [`Rng::gen_range`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.6.5/rand/trait.Rng.html#method.gen_range) states:

> This function is optimised for the case that only a single sample is made from the given range. See also the [`Uniform`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.6.5/rand/distributions/uniform/struct.Uniform.html) distribution type which may be faster if sampling from the same range repeatedly.

`Uniform` can be used to generate a single value:

```
use rand::distributions::{Distribution, Uniform}; // 0.6.5

fn main() {
    let step = Uniform::new(0, 50);
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let choice = step.sample(&mut rng);
    println!("{}", choice);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6c34a0cc61c55731c012559f11e16f2c)

Or to generate an iterator of values:

```
use rand::distributions::{Distribution, Uniform}; // 0.6.5

fn main() {
    let step = Uniform::new(0, 50);
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let choices: Vec<_> = step.sample_iter(&mut rng).take(10).collect();
    println!("{:?}", choices);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cf54f0d39c66c8fd656dc6fbcfc31978)

Comment: In Rust 1.15.1, I'm getting "unresolved name" from `rand::thread_rng`. https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=dfb901354368c0fb14bd82bda2435f95&version=stable&backtrace=0

Comment: I think something changed since every answer and even the documentation uses `rand::thread_rng`. By the way, `rand` is unstable now, so you have to add `#![feature(rand)]` to the top of your file and use the nightly rustc. All I want to do is test something; I'm *this* close to just using the C `rand()` function through FFI and calling it a day.

Comment: This works for me with Rust 1.7.0. Have to add `rand = "0.3"` into `Cargo.toml` file though.

Comment: As of rustc 1.42.0 (stable) with > rand 0.7 this appears to be the most accurate answer.

Answer (score -3):

And why don't you just use a modulo?

```
let x = rng.gen<u32>() % 25
```

so your values will be between 0 and 24. Add an offset if you need a different range.

Comment: This will give you numbers in range 0..25, but their distribution will not be uniform. It may be negligible with 25, since it is lot smaller than `u32::MAX`. But if you used this with range 0..4_000_000_000, you would find that you get the numbers in 0..294_649_297 twice as often as those in 294_649_297..4_000_000_000.