# How do I run parallel threads of computation on a partitioned array?

Tags: multithreading, random, synchronization, rust

I'm trying to distribute an array across threads and have the threads sum up portions of the array in parallel. I want thread 0 to sum elements 0 1 2 and Thread 1 sum elements 3 4 5. Thread 2 to sum 6 and 7. and Thread 3 to sum 8 and 9.

I'm new to Rust but have coded with C/C++/Java before. I've literally thrown everything and the garbage sink at this program and I was hoping I could receive some guidance.

Sorry my code is sloppy but I will clean it up when it is a finished product. Please ignore all poorly named variables/inconsistent spacing/etc.

```
use std::io;
use std::rand;
use std::sync::mpsc::{Sender, Receiver};
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::thread::Thread;

static NTHREADS: usize = 4;
static NPROCS: usize = 10;

fn main() {
    let mut a = [0; 10]; // a: [i32; 10]
    let mut endpoint = a.len() / NTHREADS;
    let mut remElements = a.len() % NTHREADS;

    for x in 0..a.len() {
        let secret_number = (rand::random::<i32>() % 100) + 1;
        a[x] = secret_number;
        println!("{}", a[x]);
    }
    let mut b = a;
    let mut x = 0;

    check_sum(&mut a);
    // serial_sum(&mut b);

    // Channels have two endpoints: the `Sender<T>` and the `Receiver<T>`,
    // where `T` is the type of the message to be transferred
    // (type annotation is superfluous)
    let (tx, rx): (Sender<i32>, Receiver<i32>) = mpsc::channel();
    let mut scale: usize = 0;

    for id in 0..NTHREADS {
        // The sender endpoint can be copied
        let thread_tx = tx.clone();
        // Each thread will send its id via the channel

        Thread::spawn(move || {
            // The thread takes ownership over `thread_tx`
            // Each thread queues a message in the channel
            let numTougherThreads: usize = NPROCS % NTHREADS;
            let numTasksPerThread: usize = NPROCS / NTHREADS;
            let mut lsum = 0;

            if id < numTougherThreads {
                let mut q = numTasksPerThread+1;
                lsum = 0;

                while q > 0 {
                    lsum = lsum + a[scale];
                    scale+=1;
                    q = q-1;
                }
                println!("Less than numToughThreads lsum: {}", lsum);
            }
            if id >= numTougherThreads {
                let mut z = numTasksPerThread;
                lsum = 0;

                while z > 0 {
                    lsum = lsum + a[scale];
                    scale +=1;
                    z = z-1;
                }    
                println!("Greater than numToughthreads lsum: {}", lsum);
            }
            // Sending is a non-blocking operation, the thread will continue
            // immediately after sending its message
            println!("thread {} finished", id);
            thread_tx.send(lsum).unwrap();
        });
    }

    // Here, all the messages are collected
    let mut globalSum = 0;
    let mut ids = Vec::with_capacity(NTHREADS);
    for _ in 0..NTHREADS {
        // The `recv` method picks a message from the channel
        // `recv` will block the current thread if there no messages      available
        ids.push(rx.recv());
    }
    println!("Global Sum: {}", globalSum);
    // Show the order in which the messages were sent

    println!("ids: {:?}", ids);
}

fn check_sum (arr: &mut [i32]) {
    let mut sum = 0;
    let mut i = 0;
    let mut size = arr.len();
    loop {
        sum += arr[i];
        i+=1;
        if i == size { break; }
    }
    println!("CheckSum is {}", sum);
}
```

So far I've gotten it to do this much. Can't figure out why threads 0 and 1 have the same sum as well as 2 and 3 doing the same thing:

```
 -5
 -49
 -32
 99
 45
 -65
 -64
 -29
 -56
 65
 CheckSum is -91
 Greater than numTough lsum: -54
 thread 2 finished
 Less than numTough lsum: -86
 thread 1 finished
 Less than numTough lsum: -86
 thread 0 finished
 Greater than numTough lsum: -54
 thread 3 finished
 Global Sum: 0
 ids: [Ok(-86), Ok(-86), Ok(-54), Ok(-54)]
```

I managed to rewrite it to work with even numbers by using the below code.

```
    while q > 0 {
        if id*s+scale == a.len() { break; }
        lsum = lsum + a[id*s+scale];
        scale +=1;
        q = q-1;
    }
    println!("Less than numToughThreads lsum: {}", lsum);
}
if id >= numTougherThreads {
    let mut z = numTasksPerThread;
    lsum = 0;
    let mut scale = 0;

    while z > 0 {
        if id*numTasksPerThread+scale == a.len() { break; }
        lsum = lsum + a[id*numTasksPerThread+scale];
        scale = scale + 1;
        z = z-1;
    }
```

Comment: Can you describe the algorithm you're trying to implement? What is the expected result?

Comment: I'm trying to distribute the array across the threads and have the threads sum up portions of the array in parallel. I want thread 0 to sum elements 0 1 2 and Thread 1 sum elements 3 4 5. Thread 2 to sum 6 and 7. and Thread 3 to sum 8 and 9

Comment: i managed to get it to work with even numbers like 20 and 100

Comment: your "question" now doesn't contain a question anymore.

Comment: Just noticed that your `check_sum` takes a `&mut [i32]`. Why `mut`? You don't want to mutate anything in that slice.

Comment: Maybe this approach is useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70851207/286335

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Welcome to Rust! :)

> Yeah at first I didn't realize each thread gets it's own copy of scale

Not only that! It also gets its own copy of `a`!

What you are trying to do could look like the following code. I guess it's easier for you to see a complete working example since you seem to be a Rust beginner and asked for guidance. I deliberately replaced `[i32; 10]` with a `Vec` since a `Vec` is *not* implicitly `Copy`able. It requires an explicit `clone()`; we cannot copy it by accident. Please note all the larger and smaller differences. The code also got a little more functional (less `mut`). I commented most of the noteworthy things:

```
extern crate rand;

use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::thread;

const NTHREADS: usize = 4; // I replaced `static` by `const`

// gets used for *all* the summing :)
fn sum<I: Iterator<Item=i32>>(iter: I) -> i32 {
    let mut s = 0;
    for x in iter {
        s += x;
    }
    s
}

fn main() {
    // We don't want to clone the whole vector into every closure.
    // So we wrap it in an `Arc`. This allows sharing it.
    // I also got rid of `mut` here by moving the computations into
    // the initialization.
    let a: Arc<Vec<_>> =
        Arc::new(
            (0..10)
                .map(|_| {
                    (rand::random::<i32>() % 100) + 1
                })
                .collect()
        );

    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel(); // types will be inferred

    { // local scope, we don't need the following variables outside
        let num_tasks_per_thread = a.len() / NTHREADS; // same here
        let num_tougher_threads = a.len() % NTHREADS; // same here
        let mut offset = 0;
        for id in 0..NTHREADS {
            let chunksize =
                if id < num_tougher_threads {
                    num_tasks_per_thread + 1
                } else {
                    num_tasks_per_thread
                };
            let my_a = a.clone();  // refers to the *same* `Vec`
            let my_tx = tx.clone();
            thread::spawn(move || {
                let end = offset + chunksize;
                let partial_sum =
                    sum( (&my_a[offset..end]).iter().cloned() );
                my_tx.send(partial_sum).unwrap();
            });
            offset += chunksize;
        }
    }

    // We can close this Sender
    drop(tx);

    // Iterator magic! Yay! global_sum does not need to be mutable
    let global_sum = sum(rx.iter());
    println!("global sum via threads    : {}", global_sum);
    println!("global sum single-threaded: {}", sum(a.iter().cloned()));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to input the size of the array, and the amount of threads from the user...is the io still buggy?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "is the io still buggy?" in this context?

Answer (score 6):

Using a crate like [crossbeam](https://crates.io/crates/crossbeam) you can write this code:

```
use crossbeam; // 0.7.3
use rand::distributions::{Distribution, Uniform}; // 0.7.3

const NTHREADS: usize = 4;

fn random_vec(length: usize) -> Vec<i32> {
    let step = Uniform::new_inclusive(1, 100);
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    step.sample_iter(&mut rng).take(length).collect()
}

fn main() {
    let numbers = random_vec(10);
    let num_tasks_per_thread = numbers.len() / NTHREADS;

    crossbeam::scope(|scope| {
        // The `collect` is important to eagerly start the threads!
        let threads: Vec<_> = numbers
            .chunks(num_tasks_per_thread)
            .map(|chunk| scope.spawn(move |_| chunk.iter().cloned().sum::<i32>()))
            .collect();

        let thread_sum: i32 = threads.into_iter().map(|t| t.join().unwrap()).sum();
        let no_thread_sum: i32 = numbers.iter().cloned().sum();

        println!("global sum via threads    : {}", thread_sum);
        println!("global sum single-threaded: {}", no_thread_sum);
    })
    .unwrap();
}
```

*Scoped threads* allow you to pass in a reference that is guaranteed to outlive the thread. You can then use the return value of the thread directly, skipping channels (which are great, just not needed here!).

I followed [How can I generate a random number within a range in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19671845/155423) to generate the random numbers. I also changed it to be the range [1,100], as I *think* that's what you meant. However, your original code is actually [-98,100], which you could also do.

[`Iterator::sum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.sum) is used to sum up an iterator of numbers.

I threw in some rough performance numbers of the thread work, ignoring the vector construction, working on 100,000,000 numbers, using Rust 1.34 and compiling in release mode:

```
| threads | time (ns) | relative time (%) |
|---------+-----------+-------------------|
|       1 |  33824667 |            100.00 |
|       2 |  16246549 |             48.03 |
|       3 |  16709280 |             49.40 |
|       4 |  14263326 |             42.17 |
|       5 |  14977901 |             44.28 |
|       6 |  12974001 |             38.36 |
|       7 |  13321743 |             39.38 |
|       8 |  13370793 |             39.53 |
```

See also:

- [How can I pass a reference to a stack variable to a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32750829/155423)

Comment: You're launching actually 5 threads instead of 4. But other than that: thread::scoped is cool! Didn't know that it already works like it's supposed to.

Comment: @sellibitze haha, good catch! But what's one extra thread among friends? ^_^. I suppose it could be fixed it by doing a floating-point division then rounding up. Or perhaps doing some [trickery with integer division](http://stackoverflow.com/a/503201/155423)?

Comment: Hold on. I just noticed that `threads` is an iterator! This is not doing what you want. It lazily launches the threads just before you ask to join it. So, they don't work concurrently.

Comment: @sellibitze Double good catch! I've added a `collect` to force the threads to start right away.

Comment: how would i install the latest bleeding-edge for ubuntu? and thanks for the response and code. The uniform distribution and timing is what I wanted to do eventually.

Comment: @ScosheRosh just [download the appropriate installer](http://www.rust-lang.org/install.html) for your platform.

Answer (score 3):

All your tasks get a copy of the `scale` variable. Thread 1 and 2 both do the same thing since each has `scale` with a value of `0` and modifies it in the same manner as the other thread.
The same goes for Thread 3 and 4.

Rust prevents you from breaking thread safety. If `scale` were shared by the threads, you would have race conditions when accessing the variable.

Please read about [closures](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/closures.html), they explain the variable copying part, and about [threading](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/concurrency.html) which explains when and how you can share variables between threads.

Comment: Yeah at first I didn't realize each thread gets it's own copy of scale