# How to choose several random numbers from an interval?

Tags: random, rust, integer, numbers

I have an interval 0..N in Rust and need to choose 3 distinct random integers (with each integer in the interval having equal probabilities to be chosen).

I want this to query random servers to cross-verify data.

How to do this in Rust?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I generate a random number within a range in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671845/how-can-i-generate-a-random-number-within-a-range-in-rust)

Comment: I think a key word you're missing in your quest is "sample". There's this but I'm not sure if it can take a "rangey"/interval instance. https://docs.rs/rand/0.8.4/rand/seq/index/fn.sample.html

Comment: Try running three steps of the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle) to get three different number from the specified range.

Comment: @Smitop My question is about generating _distinct_ numbers. So, it's not an answer.

Comment: @nelsonjchen Yes, `rand::seq::index::sample` is the answer.

Comment: @rossum Your solution is _very_ inefficient.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `rand` crate, adapting the [uniform distribution](https://docs.rs/rand/0.8.4/rand/distributions/uniform/index.html#) example

```rust
fn main() {
    use rand::distributions::Uniform;
    use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};

    let mut rng = thread_rng();
    let side = Uniform::new(-10, 10);

    for _ in 0..3 {
        println!("Point: {}", rng.sample(side));
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9c12eae03957ba2eff1b94858543d6ab)

For **distinct** numbers within the range use the [`index::sample`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.8.4/rand/seq/index/fn.sample.html):

```rust
fn main() {
    use rand::{thread_rng};

    let mut rng = thread_rng();
    let results = rand::seq::index::sample(&mut rng, 10, 3).into_vec();
    println!("{:?}", results);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6c02050cacd19532b3a9abdc58bd22c6)

Comment: You misread. I want 3 _distinct_ numbers. Your code sometimes output identical numbers.

Comment: @porton I think you should use https://docs.rs/rand/0.8.4/rand/seq/index/fn.sample.html then. Sorry if I missread.  (ill update the answers if that is what you were trying to find)

Comment: Yes, docs.rs/rand/0.8.4/rand/seq/index/fn.sample.html is what I need.